# Matrix Properties: Elementary row/column operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say I have a matrix A of arbitrary size, and I perform a finite number of both elementary row/column operations on it, obtaining matrix B.

Are there any unique properties of matrix B that would be the same as matrix A? Such that I will be able to recognize that matrix B is a result of these operations performed on matrix A.

Here are some of the stuff that I've managed to find so far:

From Wikipedia, "Elementary row operations do not change the kernel of a matrix" "Elementary column operations do not change the image, but they do change the kernel."

And I've been told on StackOverflow that "if you don't consider scaling a row/column as an elementary operation a lot more structure is maintained".

Thank you.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12172154/1179936), right?

Comment: Yup, I was advised to ask here instead.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to recognize that matrix $B$ originated from matrix $A$.
There are other matrices that can be reduced to matrix $B$ via performing elementary operations.

Comment: If I rephrased my question slightly, instead of recognizing that B originated from A, but for Matrix A and B to still share some common un-changed properties as a result of those elementary operations, will there still be an answer?

Comment: I think all other relevant properties preserved by elementary operations are listed in @Gerry Myerson's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only things you can count on are that you won't change the number of rows, the number of columns, the rank, or the nullity. If it's a square matrix, you won't change its invertibility.